# Error in v-on handler not a function error on reusable component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my VueJS, Laravel application I have a VueJS component called `SharePostModalComponent.vue`.

It has following code

```
<template>
    <div v-show="showShareModal" class="custom-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Report Post (ID: {{ postId }})</h5>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="close"
                    aria-label="Close"
                    @click="closeModal"
                >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reason">Reason for Reporting:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="reason"
                            v-model="reason"
                            placeholder="Enter the reason for reporting"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comments">Additional Comments:</label>
                        <textarea
                            class="form-control"
                            id="comments"
                            v-model="comments"
                            placeholder="Enter any additional comments"
                        ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    @click="closeModal"
                >
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    @click="submitReport"
                >
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            showShareModal: false,
            reason: "",
            comments: "",
            postId: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        openShareModal(postId) {
            this.postId = postId;
            this.showShareModal = true;
        },
        closeModal() {
            this.showShareModal = false;
        },
        submitReport() {
            // Here, you can make an API request to send the report to the backend
            // Include the reason and comments in the request payload
            const report = {
                reason: this.reason,
                comments: this.comments,
            };
            this.closeModal();
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.custom-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.modal-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modal-title {
    margin: 0;
}

.close {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal-body {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.modal-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.btn-secondary,
.btn-primary {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
    height: 100px;
    resize: vertical;
}

.input-error {
    border-color: #dc3545 !important;
}

.error-message {
    color: #dc3545;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

/* Additional Styles */

.custom-modal::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    z-index: -1;
}

.modal-content {
    position: relative;
}

.modal-footer .btn-primary {
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
}

.modal-footer .btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #0069d9;
    border-color: #0062cc;
}

.modal-footer .btn-secondary {
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #6c757d;
}

.modal-footer .btn-secondary:hover {
    background-color: #5a6268;
    border-color: #545b62;
}

.input-error:focus {
    border-color: #dc3545 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.25) !important;
}

.error-message {
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
```

I tried using this component in my `PostFeed.vue` component

```
<button
                                class="btn btn-link btn-share"
                                @click="toggleShareOptions(post.id)"
                            >
                                <i class="bi bi-reply"></i> Share
                            </button>
                            <div
                                v-if="showShareOptions[post.id]"
                                class="share-options"
                            >
                                <button
                                    v-if="showShareOptions[post.id]"
                                    @click="shareWithAdditionalText(post.id)"
                                    class="btn btn-link btn-share-option"
                                >
                                    Share with Additional Text
                                </button>
                                <!-- Include the modal component with the v-model directive and event listeners -->
                                <share-post-modal-component
                                    ref="shareModal"
                                ></share-post-modal-component>
                                <button
                                    @click="shareWithoutAdditionalText(post)"
                                    class="btn btn-link btn-share-option"
                                >
                                    Just Share
                                </button>
```

Then in my **script** I have

```
import SharePostModalComponent from "./SharePostModalComponent.vue";



components: {
        ...
        SharePostModalComponent,
    },
```

And under the methods I have

```
toggleShareOptions(postId) {
            // If the share options for the clicked post are already open, close them
            if (this.showShareOptions[postId]) {
                this.$set(this.showShareOptions, postId, false);
            } else {
                // Otherwise, close all other share options and open the share options for the clicked post
                Object.keys(this.showShareOptions).forEach((key) => {
                    this.$set(this.showShareOptions, key, false);
                });
                this.$set(this.showShareOptions, postId, true);
            }
        },
        shareWithAdditionalText(postId) {
            // Set the showModal property to true to open the modal
            this.$refs.shareModal.openShareModal(postId);
        },
        handleModalSubmit() {
            // Logic to handle the modal submit event
            console.log("Modal submitted");
        },
        shareWithoutAdditionalText(post) {
            // Implement the logic to share the post without additional text
            console.log("Just share:", post);
        },
```

But Everytime when I tried to open the modal by clicking Share with additional text link it kept giving me

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.shareModal.openShareModal is not a function"

found in

---> <PostFeed> at resources/js/components/PostFeed.vue
```

In my app.js I have

```
import SharePostModalComponent from './components/SharePostModalComponent.vue';
Vue.component('share-post-modal-component', SharePostModalComponent);
```

I'm struggling to find what mistake I'm doing here...

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Have you try to `console.log` this.$refs.shareModal, to see what you got?